# Microwave oven grill heating element not glowing

Tags: oven, microwave

Recently I have purchased a sharp branded convection microwave oven. When I tried to make grill, I found that the heating element for grill which placed at ceiling was not glowing. So I was confused that is that grilling part working or not. So I made a call to the shop from where I purchased and they said it glows only for electronic oven, not in microwave oven. But I am still confused that is that true or not.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having one of these in a kitchen I worked in. I too was confused by it.

When using the oven as a microwave the element stays off. When grilling, the element used to cycle on and off as the internal temp rises and falls. It also went off if the door was opened. It used to glow a dark orangey-red, only for a moment. It was difficult to see with the internal cabinet light on. However, it generated heat most of the time without an obvious visible glow. You can't just turn the grill on. You need to set a time as you would in microwave mode. There was no easy way to pre-heat the grill function.

In my opinion the unit was a waste of time and I only used it as a microwave. Sorry probably not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: Shouldn't  that element glow a bit at least, because it is just a metal? I operated that for around one hour in combination mode, but didn't see any visible difference for  that heating element. So how does  it generate heat? I am really confused.

Comment: @SamratAlamgir Yes the one I used did glow a dark orangey-red, only for a moment. It was difficult to see with the internal cabinet light on. However, it generated heat most of the time without an obvious visible glow. I don't know how it generates heat.  Does yours get hot?

Comment: @SamratAlamgir Can you provide a link to the exact model? Perhaps someone with electrical engineering knowledge would know exactly how the element generates heat.  Do Sharp have a customer careline in your region?